# nginx - Completely case-insensitive URL matching and file lookup

Tags: nginx

I want all URLs on my server to be case-insensitive, in both directions. With that I mean: If the user requests `index.html`, but the file is called `Index.html`, they should still get it. If they request `Index.html`, but it's called `index.html`, they should still get it.

My server runs on Linux whose file system is case-sensitive by default, but can this be worked around by nginx?

Comment: No. Nginx relies on the file system for case sensitivity.

Comment: @RichardSmith That sucks, but there's no way people haven't tried to do this before. Imagine migrating from a Windows to a Linux server and having to rename thousands of files in your server; that sounds extremely error-prone. I refuse to believe there's no way of achieving this, given nginx's large user base. Plugin, maybe?